# Taylor approximation of exp(x) function for large x

Tags: taylor-expansion, factorial, computational-mathematics

```
import numpy
from scipy.special import factorial

def Tn_exp(x):

    # Number of terms for Taylor Series
    MAX_N = 25 + numpy.abs(x)*3 
    
    # Coefficients of Taylor Series
    p = numpy.arange(MAX_N-1, -1, -1)

    # check the sign of x and do the calculation
    if x >= 0:
        Tn = 1/factorial(MAX_N)
        for coefficient in p:
            Tn = Tn * x + 1/factorial(coefficient)
    else:
        Tn = 1/factorial(MAX_N) * (-1)**MAX_N
        for coefficient in p:
            Tn = Tn * x + 1/factorial(coefficient) * (-1)**coefficient
        Tn = 1/Tn
    
    return Tn
```

I write a Python function to approximate the value of $\exp(x)$ by Taylor Series. It works well for small $x$ but it cannot deal with very large $x$ due to the problem of $x!$. It only shows `inf` for any $x > 170$ and will cause missing values for $\frac{1}{x!}$. Could someone give some ideas how to deal with this problem since I also consider the situation that $x$ is not an integer? Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, part of the problem is you are using Python, which doesn’t have infinite precision.

Comment: It might work better to compute the terms recursively, rather than recomputing factorials, etc. $$a_0=1, a_{n+1}=\frac{x a_n}{n+1}$$ then sum $a_i.$

Comment: Is it possible to deal with the case that x is not an integer and x can be as large as 709, which is the largest for numpy.exp()?

Comment: Why not write $e^x =10^{x\log_{10}(e)}$?

Comment: Probably worth your while to look at how the pros do it, including range reduction. See "Computer Approximations" by Hart, Cheney, et al.

Comment: You should use built in exp function, but if you insist on writing your own, use $e^{2x} = \left(e^x\right)^2$ until $x < 1$ then use taylor approx.

Comment: If you just want to compute the value for larger values of $x,$ then the base $10$ approach @MarkViola mentions is best. Compute $\alpha=\log_{10}e.$ Compute $\beta=x\alpha.$ Let $n$ be the integer part of $w$ and $\gamma$ be the fractional part. Then your answer is $10^{\gamma}\cdot 10^n,$ where, since $0\leq \gamma<1,$ you have $1\leq 10^{\gamma}<10.$  You should pass this number as a pair, $(10^{\gamma},n),$ because the whole reason Python’s built-in operation doesn’t work for values is that $e^{710}$ is bigger than the maximum floating point variable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews (+1) for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using: $$a_0=1, a_{n+1}=\frac{xa_n}{n+1},$$ we avoid dealing with huge factorials. Then we sum up enough $a_i.$

```
def Tn_exp(x):
    if x<0: 
        return 1/Tn_exp(-x)

    MaxN = int(3*x+25)
    a = 1.0
    sum = 1.0
    for i in  range(1,MaxN+1):
        a = a/i*x
        sum += a
    return sum
```

We could quit early if `i>2x` and `a` is very small compared to `sum`. That’s because the result of the terms will add up to less than $a.$

If you are not specifically trying to compute the Taylor series, just want $\exp$ implemented for larger $x,$ you won’t be able to do so using floating points, because the reason the built-in Python function can’t compute $\exp(710)$ is that the value overflows Python’s floating point.

If your only goal is computing $e^x$ for larger $x,$ it is easier to use $\log_{10}e$ and return pairs $(y,n)$ where $y$ is a real number, $1\leq y<10$ and $n$ is an integer, and the pair represents $y\cdot 10^n.$  Specifically:

```
import math

Loge10=math.log(10)
Log10e=1/Loge10

def better_exp(x):
    a = x*Log10e
    n = math.floor(a)
    b = a-n
    return (math.exp(b*Loge10),n)
```

This will be much faster.

The pairs $(y,n)$ are necessary because for larger $x,$ $e^x$ is larger than the maximum floating point value allowed for a Python floating point number.

Comment: Is it possible to deal with the case that x is not an integer and x can be as large as 709, which is the largest for numpy.exp()?

Comment: Edited to deal with non-integers. The only problem with the original version was I didn't endure MaxN was an integer

Comment: Presumably, the problem at $709$ is that you've maxed out Python's internal floating point storage.

Comment: Edited to do `a=a/i*x` rather than `a=a*x/i`, which reduces the overflow case. Now I overflow at $x=710$ or higher, like the builtin algorithm.

Comment: But you could do some scaling. So if you return two values, $m,e$ to represent $m\cdot 10^e$ then you can compute almost any exponent for which the loop is not unreasonably long. So when `sum` becomes greater than `1.0e+300` divide both `sum` and `a` by  `1.0e+100` and then return `sum` and `100j` where `j` is the number of times you've scaled everything smaller. I computed $e^{1000}$ this way and got: `(1.9700711140170494e+234, 200)` which translates as $$1.9700711140170494\cdot 10^{434}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use the identity
$${\displaystyle e^{x}=1+{\cfrac {x}{1-{\cfrac {x}{x+2-{\cfrac {2x}{x+3-{\cfrac {3x}{x+4-\ddots }}}}}}}}}
$$
Due to Euler.

Comment: Without some sense of the speed of convergence of this, hard to see how it helps.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Unfortunately I couldn't find the rate of convergence of this - hopefully someone can figure it out